# Android NDK: Problems in device but working fine in emulator. Unsatisfied link error for libs

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have made an android app in ndk which includes gmp and some other prebuilt libraries. The application runs fine in the emulator(Nexus 4, ARM) but is not working on real mobiles. I am getting unsatisfied link errors while running on online mobiles. How to fix it?

Log file when running on device:

```
11-05 15:18:45.081: D/dalvikvm(7831): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.myproject-1/libgmp.so 0x4298e3a8
11-05 15:18:45.081: E/dalvikvm(7831): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.example.myproject-1/libgmp.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "localeconv" referenced by "libgmp.so"...
11-05 15:18:45.081: W/dalvikvm(7831): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/myproject/MainActivity;
11-05 15:18:45.081: W/dalvikvm(7831): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/myproject/MainActivity;)
11-05 15:18:45.081: D/AndroidRuntime(7831): Shutting down VM
11-05 15:18:45.081: W/dalvikvm(7831): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b8ad58)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831): Process: com.example.myproject, PID: 7831
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "localeconv" referenced by "libgmp.so"...
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at com.example.myproject.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:20)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
11-05 15:18:45.101: E/AndroidRuntime(7831):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: 38 questions posted and only 4 accepted in 3 years - a tough customer.

Answer (score 2):

Is the name of your library `libgmp.so`? The log says it has a reference to "localeconv" that is only found on the emulator. That symbol should be in the C++ library. Are the API levels the same in the emulator and the device?

Comment: yes. gmp is the name of the library. How to check the apk to see if it's included?

Comment: The apk is a zip file, so just check the contents of it. Then check what's going on with your build/packing code if it's not there

Comment: I can see libgmp.so file after extraction in the apk file

Comment: api version of emulator is 23 and for mobile its 19. Guess api level 19 is not that old to have such bugs. And yeah libgmp.so is the lib file. I will check with api level 19 in emulator for completeness

Comment: Try running the emulator with API 19. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/localeconv/ localeconv should be standard. Also there are some builds of GMP for android (https://github.com/Rupan/gmp) that you could try for comparison

Comment: I am already using Rupan/gmp files. Do you think there could be a problem due to the differences in the api levels?

Comment: I can't tell. Maybe ask there or try building your own binary libraries instead of using theirs. I'd ask on that github repo.

Comment: yep. I can't run it on api 19 on emulator. Facing similar errors